# How can I delete a record from database in a ajax request in magento

Tags: magento

I have created custom module and I am working on record deletion but its not working. Code which I am using is

```
   $keyId=$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams('id');
   $model = Mage::getModel('groupprice/groupprice');
    try {
    $model->setId($keyId)->delete();
    echo "Data deleted successfully.";

    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Is anything wrong ?
This code is working in a simple request but not working with ajax request .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change code and use `getPost`

```
$keyId=$params = $this->getRequest()->getPost('id');
```

Hope this wil help.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**

```
$keyId=$params = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$model = Mage::getModel('groupprice/groupprice');
try 
{
    $model->setId($keyId)->delete();
    echo "Data deleted successfully.";

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
```